Finding free subgroup $F_2$ in the free product $\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{5\mathbb{Z}} * \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{6\mathbb{Z}}$
Is there any free group isomorphic to $F_2$ contained in the free product group $\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{5 \mathbb{Z}}* \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{6 \mathbb{Z}}?$
Let $\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{5\mathbb{Z}}= \langle a \mid a^5=1 \rangle$ and $\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{6\mathbb{Z}}= \langle b \mid b^6=1 \rangle$. Clearly $ab,ba$ these two elements  are of infinite order in the free product. I want to show that the group generated by $\langle ab, ba\rangle$ is a free subgroup of the free product. How to show that?

Do you have a copy of Serre's book called Trees?

I'm thinking you might be able to do this with the Kurosh subgroup theorem.

It's not too hard to show by bare hands that $x:=ab$ and $y:=ba$ generate a free subgroup. A reduced word in $x$ and $y$ cannot contain any power of $a^{\pm 1}$ or $b^{\pm 1}$ larger than $2$, and so cannot evaluate to the identity in the free product.

Note: they're quotient sets, not fractions. We write $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$. not $\frac{\Bbb Z}{n\Bbb Z}$.

You can use topological methods for the proof, namely Bass-Serre theory.
According to that theory, the group $\mathbb Z / 5 \mathbb Z * \Bbb Z / 6 \mathbb Z$ acts freely on a bipartite infinite tree $T$ having a one-edge fundamental domain $E$, with one endpoint $V$ of valence 5 and opposite endpoint $W$ of valence $6$. The element $a$ cyclically permutes the edges incident to $V$, and $b$ cyclically permutes the edges incident to $W$.
The idea is now to construct a subtree $\tau \subset T$ on which the rank 2 free group $\langle C \rangle * \langle D \rangle$ acts freely and properly discontinuously, where the action of $C$ on $\tau$ coincides with the restriction of the action of $ab$ on $T$, and the action of $D$ on $\tau$ coincides with the restriction of the action of $ba$ on $T$.
Here's a description of $\tau$. The edge $a^{-1}E$ connects $W' = a^{-1}W$ to $V=aV$, and the edge $b^{-1} E$ connects $V'=b^{-1} V$ to $W=BW$. Consider $\tau_0 = a^{-1} E \cup E \cup b^{-1} E$, a 3-edge subtree. Note that $ab\tau \cap \tau_0 = W$ and $ba\tau \cap \tau_0 = V$. It follows that $\tau_0$ is a fundamental domain for an action of the subgroup generated by $C=ab$ and $D=ba$, and moreover any reduced word in $C$ and $D$ takes $\tau_0$ off of itself. Thus $C,D$ generate a free action of the free group $\langle C,D \rangle$ on a subtree $\tau \subset T$ with fundamental domain $\tau_0$.
If you like, you can actually visualize $T$ (and $\tau$) in the hyperbolic plane. Pick any long enough segment $E$ with endpoints $V,W$, represent $a$ by a rotation of angle $2\pi/5$ around $V$, and represent $b$ by a rotation of angle $2\pi/6$ around $W$. Using a bit of hyperbolic trigonometry one can prove that if $E$ is long enough then the action of $\langle a,b \rangle$ embeds $T$ into $\mathbb H^2$ with fundamental domain $E$. To see this in a bit more detail, let $\rho_a$ be the ray bisecting the angle $E,aE$, let $\rho_{a^{-1}}$ be the ray bisecting the angle $E,a^{-1}E$, and similarly for $\rho_b$ and $\rho_{b^{-1}}$. If $E$ is long enough, the rays $\rho_a$ and $\rho_{b^{-1}}$ are disjoint, and the rays $\rho_b$ and $\rho_{a^{-1}}$ are disjoint, and those four rays bound a region $R$ which is disjoint from all its translates under the action of $\langle a,b \rangle$. There is one translate of $E$ in each translate of $R$.

I do not know Bass Serre Theory . Is is possible to proof without using that.

Well you have three different proofs on this page: two in answers and one in the comments.

Yeah actually I am trying the answer on the comment section  "a reduced word can't contain any power of $a^{\pm 1}$  or $ b^{\pm 1}$  larger than $2$. I do not know how it is easy to show .
,

I would nonetheless recommend that if you really want to learn this topic, learn about Bass-Serre theory. Serre's book Trees is a great start.

Okay thanks I will start this book.


Is there any free group isomorphic to $F_2$ contained in the free product group $\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{5 \mathbb{Z}}* \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{6 \mathbb{Z}}?$

Yes.
The group is "large".

Definition: A large group is a group with a finite index subgroup that maps onto the free group $F_2$ of rank $2$.

A free product $H\ast K$ (with $H,K$ nontrivial) is large iff either:

$H$ and $K$ have nontrivial finite homomorphic images $H',K'$ such that $\{|H'|, |K'|\}\neq \{2\}$, or
either $H$ or $K$  is large.

Reference:
Pride, S., J. (1980) The Concept of “Largeness” in Group Theory, in Word Problems II, Studies in Logic and the Foundations of Mathematics, Vol. 95 (1980).

Yes, I realise I've nuked it.

By any chance,  do you know the cardinality of $F_2?$

It's $\aleph_0$, @calcll.
